# What would this be classed as, Search, login or something different?

Tags: web

I have been asked by a client something I have never really come across before and wondered if anyone could classify it for me, so that I can work out how to design it.

Basically they would like a box in which the user types in a code, the first part of this code will determine which page they are then sent to.  This page will not have search results, I see it as a more complicated version of a button with a link.

Please could you help?

Many thanks

Comment: If the first part determines where they go, what does the second part do?

Comment: Sounds like a keyword search or a meta-data driven search.  Is that what they are after?

Comment: The second part of the code will not do anything, it will only be the first few letters that will determin which of the two pages they are directed to.

I don't think it is a keyword search.  I personally would much rather place two button options on the page, but my client wants the user to be able to put in the code to reach the page.

Does that make it any clearer?

Comment: Is the code perhaps something they'll print inside cereal boxes or something? Maybe they want something that proves the customer bought their product.

Answer (score 1):

You may implement this as a table search. Say the table is something like:

```
{"133"=>1, "147"=>1, "158"=>2, "342"=>3}
```

So that the code 133 sends the user to page 1, the code 147 - also to page 1, the code 158 to page 2 etc. Your program will need to extract the code (say from a text box), look it up in the table, and send the user to the proper page.

This is similar in spirit to a [Dispatch Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table). If you specify a preferred programming language, I may be able to find more specific information.

Comment: Thank you Yuval, I have not come across this method before, do you know where I can find more information on it please?